# add another child to parent-child dynamic collapsable list bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dynamic

I found a example of a dynamic collapsable list using jquery and bootstrap([click here](http://www.bootply.com/USHFIFYSK5)). I need to create a similar list but I need to go one level deeper. So right now each list has a parent and a child. But I need to have another parent child relationship within the child list. So essentinally I would be able to click list one, which shows a list, and than if I click on of those list items it would open another list. I hope that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---JS---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('label.tree-toggler').click(function (){
  $('.abc1').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('ul.tree').hasClass('in')){
         $(this).children('ul.tree').removeClass('in');
       }
  });
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').delay(300).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass('in');
    next();
  });
});

});
```

---HTML---

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">Loreum Ipsum</label>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li class="abc1"><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">List 1</label>
           <ul class="nav nav-list tree collapse in abc">
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="abc1"><label class="tree-toggler nav-header ">List 2</label>
         <ul class="nav nav-list tree collapse abc">
           <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="abc1"><label class="tree-toggler nav-header ">List 3</label>
         <ul class="nav nav-list tree collapse abc">
           <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="abc1"><label class="tree-toggler nav-header ">List 4</label>
         <ul class="nav nav-list tree collapse abc">
           <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Loreum Ipsum</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried just adding another list item into one of the child lists with similar classes as the parents with no success. I feel like I need to fix the javascript and create a new class, but I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: please show relevant code of what you have tried/your current progress

Comment: The link is to a 'fiddle' site which shows what I've tried